# Error in RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

Trying to use `dbWriteTable` with the `RSQLite` driver results in the following error:

```
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'character'
```

My R Script:

```
Con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="fake.db")
dbWriteTable(Con, "tabeltest", myData.Frame)
dbWriteTable(Con, "anotherTable", myData.Frame)
dbWriteTable(Con, "lastTable", myData.Frame)
```

I am trying to re-create this bug with a smaller data.frame, but cannot... 
(which makes this much more difficult to triage)

If I change `Con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="fake.db")` to `Con <- dbConnect(SQLite(force.reload=T), dbname="fake.db")` I get:

```
In sqliteInitDriver(max.con, fetch.default.rec, force.reload, shared.cache) :RS-DBI driver warning: (mgr->drvData was not freed (some memory leaked))
```

I am on Windows 7 running R 3.02

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `RMySQL` will not write to a database if a table has a column of all `NULL` values in multiple tables.

I was able to successfully write to the tables by removing the null columns.

I have made this a community wiki so we can 
1) triage the problem 2) develop a data.frame that can recreate the problem, and 3) issue a pull request to fix the problem.